# Best index data structure for querying text files

Tags: algorithm, search, indexing, data-structures

I have a very large text file (50GB+). I would like to perform searches of this text file, specifically:

- Be able to return all exact occurrences of a query string, and what follows it in sequence.
- At each time point, I want to perform a search for a single query string. I don't care about multiple query matching.
- I don't care about pattern matching. I'm only interested in exact matches.
- I also want to be able to find all occurrences and their locations in the text file very fast.

I can build an index of this file but it needs to remain somewhat small (of the order of the size of the input text file).
What is the fastest/optimal data structure or index to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Suffix Array or a *[Compressed Suffix Array (CSA)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compressed_suffix_array)* would be an optimal choice for your requirement. Suffix Arrays are a data structure that allows for fast pattern matching and can be stored compactly, making them a suitable choice for large text files.

A Suffix Array is a sorted array of all the suffixes of a given text. It can be built in `O(n log n)` time, where `n` is the length of the text. To search for an exact match of a query string in the Suffix Array, you can use binary search, which takes `O(m log n)` time, where `m` is the length of the query string.

Compressed Suffix Array (CSA) comes to picture if you need a more ***space-efficient*** representation of the Suffix Array. The CSA reduces space usage significantly while still allowing for fast search operations.

To build a Compressed Suffix Array, you can:

1. Construct the Suffix Array for the given text file.
2. Compress the Suffix Array using techniques like *[Run-Length Encoding (RLE)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding)*, *[Burrows-Wheeler Transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burrows%E2%80%93Wheeler_transform)* (BWT), or any other compression algorithms. I would go with any of the first two.

Once you have the Compressed Suffix Array, you can perform searches quickly by ***decompressing only the necessary parts of the array***. This way, you can achieve a good balance between space usage and search performance.

**REFERENCES AND USEFUL READS:**

1. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/suffix-array-set-1-introduction/
2. https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/69677
3. https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-642-16321-0_36